# Как заменить фона окна на видео?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, видео, pygame

У меня есть программа - мини-игра "орёл или решка". Всё работает, только осталось сделать замену фона окна на видео (строки 36, 39, 42, 45), не получается этого сделать. 
Можно использовать любые библиотеки, главное чтобы работало.

```
import pygame
import random

# Инициализация Pygame
pygame.init()

# Размеры окна
win_width = 1920
win_height = 1080

# Создание окна
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Heads or Tails")

# Загрузка изображений и шрифта
bg = pygame.image.load("eagle.png")
exit_button = pygame.image.load("coin_exit_button.png")
font = pygame.font.Font("cf.ttf", 60)

# Координаты кнопки выхода
exit_button_x = 50
exit_button_y = 50

# Счетчики выпавших орлов и решек
e_counter = 0
n_counter = 0

# Значения res и last_res
res = "none"
last_res = "e"


# Функция для изменения фона окна и возвращения нового значения last_res
def throw(res, last_res):
    if last_res == "e" and res == "e":
        # Заменить фон на видео "etel.mp4"
        pass
    elif last_res == "e" and res == "n":
        # Заменить фон на видео "etnl.mp4"
        pass
    elif last_res == "n" and res == "n":
        # Заменить фон на видео "ntnl.mp4"
        pass
    elif last_res == "n" and res == "e":
        # Заменить фон на видео "ntel.mp4"
        pass

        # Воспроизвести видео

    return res


# Основной цикл программы
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    clock.tick(60)  # Ограничение частоты обновления экрана (60 кадров в секунду)

    # Обработка событий
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Получение координат клика мыши
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            # Проверка, был ли клик на кнопке выхода
            if exit_button_x <= mouse_x <= exit_button_x + exit_button.get_width() and \
                    exit_button_y <= mouse_y <= exit_button_y + exit_button.get_height():
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or \
                    event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Выбор случайного значения для res - "e" или "n"
                res = random.choice(["e", "n"])

                # Изменение счетчиков орлов и решек
                if res == "e":
                    e_counter += 1
                elif res == "n":
                    n_counter += 1

                    # Вызов функции throw
                last_res = throw(res, last_res)

                # Отрисовка фона и кнопки выхода
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(exit_button, (exit_button_x, exit_button_y))

    # Отрисовка текста счетчика орлов и решек
    e_counter_text = font.render(f"Орёл: {e_counter}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    n_counter_text = font.render(f"Решка: {n_counter}", True, (255, 255, 255))

    win.blit(e_counter_text, (1500, 15))
    win.blit(n_counter_text, (1500, 100))

    pygame.display.flip()  # Обновление экрана

# Завершение программы
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Ответ как добавить видео в pygame [дан тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365388/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5-pygame/1365882#1365882)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, примерно так:

```
import cv2                                                           # +++
import pygame
import random

# Инициализация Pygame
pygame.init()

# Размеры окна      # установите свое
win_width = 600     # 
win_height = 600    # 

# Создание окна
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Heads or Tails")

# Загрузка изображений и шрифта
bg = pygame.image.load("im.png")                                 # установите свое
exit_button = pygame.image.load("Ok.png")                        # установите свое
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)                                # установите свое

# Координаты кнопки выхода
exit_button_x = 50
exit_button_y = 50

# Счетчики выпавших орлов и решек
e_counter = 0
n_counter = 0

# Значения res и last_res
res = "none"
last_res = "e"
video = None                                                         # +++

# Ф-я для изм-я фона окна и возвр-я нового значения last_res
def throw(res, last_res):
    if last_res == "e" and res == "e":
        # Заменить фон на видео "etel.mp4"
        video = cv2.VideoCapture("2021-05-11 16-12-08.mp4")     # установите свое
    elif last_res == "e" and res == "n":
        # Заменить фон на видео "etnl.mp4"
        video = cv2.VideoCapture("video6.avi")                  # установите свое
    elif last_res == "n" and res == "n":
        # Заменить фон на видео "ntnl.mp4"
        video = cv2.VideoCapture("video6.avi")                  # установите свое
    elif last_res == "n" and res == "e":
        # Заменить фон на видео "ntel.mp4"
        video = cv2.VideoCapture("Samonastrojka.avi")           # установите свое 
    else:                   #  на всякий случай 
        print('# ??? ' * 7)   
        video = None        

    return res, video                                           # !!! +++ video


# Основной цикл программы
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    clock.tick(60)  

    # Обработка событий
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Получение координат клика мыши
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            # Проверка, был ли клик на кнопке выхода
            if exit_button_x <= mouse_x <= exit_button_x + exit_button.get_width() and \
                    exit_button_y <= mouse_y <= exit_button_y + exit_button.get_height():
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or \
                    event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Выбор случайного значения для res - "e" или "n"
                res = random.choice(["e", "n"])

                # Изменение счетчиков орлов и решек
                if res == "e":
                    e_counter += 1
                elif res == "n":
                    n_counter += 1

                # Вызов функции throw
                last_res, video = throw(res, last_res)           # !!! +++ video
                print(f'{type(video)}') #

# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv Воспроизвести видео  
                if video:
                    success, video_image = video.read()
                    fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
                    window = pygame.display.set_mode(video_image.shape[1::-1])                
                    run = success
                    while run:
                        clock.tick(fps)
                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                run = False
                            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:        # +++
                                    run = False                                
                        success, video_image = video.read()
                        if success:
                            video_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(
                                video_image.tobytes(), 
                                video_image.shape[1::-1], 
                                "BGR"
                            )
                        else:
                            run = False
                            
                        window.blit(video_surf, (0, 0))
                        pygame.display.flip()                
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Воспроизвести видео                     

    # Отрисовка фона и кнопки выхода
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(exit_button, (exit_button_x, exit_button_y))

    # Отрисовка текста счетчика орлов и решек;  установите свое vvvvvvvvvvv  # !!!
    e_counter_text = font.render(f"Orel    {e_counter}", True, (255, 55, 55))
    n_counter_text = font.render(f"Reshka  {n_counter}", True, (155, 255, 55))

    win.blit(e_counter_text, (400, 15))                      # установите свое
    win.blit(n_counter_text, (400, 100))                     # установите свое

    pygame.display.flip()  # Обновление экрана

# Завершение программы
pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @IOKFO что не так?